# MySql Master-Slave Repllication with Sync of existing data

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I am using MySQL 5.5

I have successfully configured master slave. It is working for all new updates.
But,I want to configure master slave with existing data

My database contains huge data. It has xmls and PDFs stored in DB. So taking dump and importing in slave will take more time.

I want to configured with no down time.